# How do I capture a text through dynamic xpath in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and this is my first post here. Please bear my ignorance and I tried searching to the best of my knowledge.
Below is the html from which I need to capture the xpath on the screen if 'btn-success' is available. Please help me.

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-xs-10 ng-scope">
<div id="dashboard" class="container-fluid" ng-init="populateDropDown()" 
style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div style="color: white;">
<!-- ngRepeat: n in tapplications track by $index -->
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="n in tapplications track by $index">
<!-- end ngRepeat: n in tapplications track by $index -->
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="n in tapplications track by $index">
<!-- end ngRepeat: n in tapplications track by $index -->
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="n in tapplications track by $index">
<button class="btn ng-binding **btn-success**" ng-click="reload(n.app_seq)" 
ng-hide="n.app_name == 'GCP'" ng-class="{'btn-default':!CSI, 'btn-
success':CSI}" type="button" style="">
```

Comment: Please edit your post with what you have tried.

Comment: Please format your code with indentation

Comment: This is what I tried but it doesn't work : 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-scope'][text()='btn-
    success']"))

Comment: This button contains `**btn-success**` surrounded by two asterisks, so you need to use: `//button[ contains( @class, '**btn-success**' )]`

Comment: @krokodilko My guess is that ** is OPs way of highlighting that attribute.

Comment: @krokodilco, I tried to bold the text I required - 'btn-success' and it came out with two asterisks. I shall check if the above works and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @PradeepSomisetty Please provide some more details

Comment: @VijendranSelvarajah Can you explain the downvote please so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `class` name to locate the element like this

```
WebElement btn_success = driver.findElement(By.class("btn ng-binding **btn-success**"));
```

For the attribute value use `getAttribute()` method

```
String text_success=btn_success.getAttribute("class");
System.out.println(text_success);
```